# High severity vulnerabilities in Vue.js project with 'vue-svg-loader' dependency: 'nth-check', 'css-select', 'svgo' - how to fix and resolve?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I'm trying to run a vue version 2 project, but when running it returns the error below:

```
# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install vue-svg-loader@0.16.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/vue-svg-loader/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/vue-svg-loader/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/vue-svg-loader/node_modules/svgo
      vue-svg-loader  0.5.0 - 0.10.0 || >=0.17.0-beta.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/vue-svg-loader

4 high severity vulnerabilities
```

I've run "npm audit fix --force" but it doesn't work.

I've run "npm audit fix --force" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone not using svgo and wanting to get rid of the svgo dependency with the security risks, here's what i did:

uninstalled the loader using npm
copied this file to my project (as vue-svg-inline-loader.js): https://github.com/oliverfindl/vue-svg-inline-loader/blob/master/src/index.js
removed the svgo stuff from there (it also has to be removed from the webpack config if there's still an svgo option)

pointed webpack config to the new, local loader:

```
cfg.resolveLoader.alias = {
    'vue-svg-inline-loader': path.resolve(__dirname, 'loaders', 'vue-svg-inline-loader.js')
};
```